# Unable to call a function within a function with a FB reference

Tags: java, javascript, facebook

I am trying to get the username from Facebook, I have most of the code however I am not getting data back from the function. The two codes need to be separated so I can call the username in flash (this code is working fine) just need to pass the "username" from the JavaScript.

```
FB.api('/me?fields=username', function FB(FBusername) { 
    UserName = FBusername.username});


function returndata(){
    FB(FBusername);
    get = UserName
    return get


 };
```

Comment: Hi @Amit Kumar, what did you edited?

Comment: Hi, Nothing except few grammatical mistakes, Don't worry.

Comment: Ok thanks, :) sorry for the inconvenience i was adding this form my mobile phone

Comment: No, not a problem at all, For further Post Read [Editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). This will help you to post new question in a proper format

Comment: Any one that can help me with this problem ?