# Unable to pass a response form facebook to another function

Tags: javascript, facebook, function, facebook-graph-api

If you view this question thank you in advance!, I am working on pulling data from Facebook.

I am trying to pull the username from Facebook so i can use it in a later stage I have embedded the following code in the FB Root div.

I know the retrieve works! however i am not able to pass it on to the function `returndata` I am relative new to javascript could you please help me out? i have tried everything

There is an alert in there to check if it is retrieving data

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function()
     {
        var appId = "121070974711874";

        // If logging in as a Facebook canvas application use this URL.
        var redirectUrl = "http://apps.facebook.com/bggressive";

        // If logging in as a website do this. Be sure to add the host to your           application's App Domain list. 
        var redirectUrl = window.location.href;

        // If the user did not grant the app authorization go ahead and tell them that. Stop code execution.
        if (0 <= window.location.href.indexOf ("error_reason"))
        {
             $(document.body).append ("<p>Authorization denied!</p>");
             return;
        }


       // When the Facebook SDK script has finished loading init the
       // SDK and then get the login status of the user. The status is
       // reported in the handler.
       window.fbAsyncInit = function()
       {
           FB.init({
                     appId : appId,
                     status : true,
                     cookie : true,
                     oauth : true
           });
           FB.getLoginStatus (onCheckLoginStatus);
       };

       (function(d)
       {
          var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
          d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
       }(document));


       function onCheckLoginStatus (response)
       {
          if (response.status != "connected")
          {
              top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent (redirectUrl) + "&scope=user_photos,friends_photos";
          }
          else
          {
              FB.api('/me', function(response) 
              {
                  PASON = response.username
                  alert(response.username)
              });
          }
       }
   });

   function returndata()
   {
      get = PASON
      return get
   };

</script>
```

Comment: Instead of asking the same question 4 times, you should edit your original to be more clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885899/not-getting-data-form-java-function-in-another-function, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849255/unable-to-get-object-out-of-function, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825385/unable-to-call-a-function-within-a-function-with-a-fb-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are calling the function `returndata()` at any random point which you can't do. The reason is- the variable `PASON` is assigned value asynchronously. So, you have to code in such a way that you call `returndata()` after the value is assigned!

Its not quite clear what you are trying to do with the function `returndata()`. But, I hope your concept is clear now.

Comment: And i also want to pass this to AS3 for an interactive flash movie

Comment: Have you understood the concept? You can now implement it in any way you wish. for eg: you can save your variable in a SESSION variable after the response and use it anywhere in the future. OR, you can set this variable in a script and get it at any time..

Comment: Hi, no i dont know how, i am a AS3 developer but i am having difficulties with this...  Later on i will use this data to retrieve multiple thing by embedding it in a url. But for the moment i just need to have return data give me the username.response

Comment: If you are just looking for the userId of the current user, instead of getting this from a function , simpl call `/me` at any point after login and get the userId of the user..

Comment: But if you still want to use this kind of function, try this- make a global variable (similar to appID), say `PASON`, then after getting response call function `setData()` and assign the value to your global variable. Then you can use the function `returndata()` at any time and get the response.

Comment: Can you show me a piece of code to do this? this is the first time i am touching Javascript